# Seaborn barplot to display two bars for each column's value w.r.t. a categorical X

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization

Can anyone please help me do this? I can't find the right solution.

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

and I want a seaborn barplot to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn tends to prefer the "long" format of the data (one row per one observation) rather than "wide". To convert "wide" to "long", you can use the `.melt()` method in Pandas like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df_wide = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "Name": list("ABCDEFG"),
    "A"   : np.random.randint(0,10,7),
    "B"   : np.random.randint(0,10,7),
})

df_long = df_wide.melt(id_vars="Name", var_name="Measure Name", value_name="Measure")
```

When you have the data in a suitable format, you can use seaborn's `catplot()` to generate the plot, styling it as required:

```
sns.catplot(x="Name", y="Measure", hue="Measure Name", data=df_long, kind="bar", ci=False)
```

[image]